# Formula Omits Adjacent Cells error EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I am creating a excel sheet with sum formula.

```
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage("D:\ExcelTemplate.xlsx");
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
ws.Cells["A5"].Formula = "=SUM(A3:A4)";
```

but resultant A5 cell is displaying error "Formula Omits Adjacent Cells error"(It is also displaying the sum of A3 and A4 in A5 ofcourse). 
When i am trying to read A5 cell i am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

```
string strA5 = ws.Cells["A5"].Value.ToString();
```

Please help to resolve this. 
Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, EPPlus doesn't have a calculation engine. This means cell A5 doesn't actually contain the calculated formula result value for "=SUM(A3:A4)". And judging from your code, I suspect A5 didn't exist with a value, only a formula part. (Yes there are 2 parts for each cell: a formula part and a value part). So something like this:

```
ws.Cells["A5"].Value.ToString();
```

will fail with your "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

Comment: Hi,
A5 cell is resulting the sum of A3 and A4 but with Omit error.
I am getting the output result, but i am unable to read the A5 cell value.What do u think,? is there any problem with my code..??
Pls help to find solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of EpPlus 4.0.1.1, there is a calculation engine and an extension method `Calculate(this ExcelRangeBase range)`. Invoke it before accessing `Value` property:

```
ws.Cells["A5"].Calculate();
```

and `ws.Cells["A5"].Value` will return the expected result.